# How to tell if ServerSocket client disconnected?

Tags: android, sockets, serversocket

My server-type app listens on a ServerSocket and accepts a connection from a client. I can then read and write to it fine. What I can't figure out is how to detect if the client disconnected. MySocket.isConnected() function continues returning true. Likewise isClosed() always returns false.

I've read in other places that the *only* way to tell is to try to read or write it and detect an Exception. **Is that the only way?**

Comment: Basically, yes. [`isConnected()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#isConnected()) returns true even after the socket is closed, and [`isClosed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#isClosed()) returns true only when `close()` has been called on the server side. If the client disconnects gracefully, subsequent reads will return 0 bytes. If the client is lost abnormally, that can take awhile to discover, use [`setKeepAlive()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#setKeepAlive(boolean)) to help address that.

Comment: Your comment is 100% correct I've found. But I still have a problem: I actually have TWO server sockets connected. I can't try reads because the first one I tried to read would *block* even if the 2nd one had disconnected. I guess I could try using a Java NIO Selector but that looks pretty gnarly to use. Also KeepAlives didn't appear to do anything for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution to my problem. Here's what I did:

- I gave up on my Android version and ported my server to Windows.
- In my server app I created two Event objects using **CreateEvent()**.
- I spawned two threads, one for each socket, using **CreateThread()**.
- Each thread issues a blocking read on it's socket.
- On read *success*, each thread processes the received data. On read *failure* (e.g. disconnect), I set it's event to signalled using **SetEvent()**.
- In the server app, I wait on both events using **WaitForMultipleObjects()**. If either event fires, I take appropriate appropriate action on the disconnect (for now, I just exit).

Maybe not an answer to my original question, but it fills my requirements.